# Whats the build version is used in the Bq release of Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling, versions

I just wanted to know the exact build version being used in the Bq release of the Ubuntu touch phone.

Is this Ubuntu-rtm 14.09 ? I see some parts are missing in my current ubuntu-touch. May be someone can help me to get the right build and move completely to Ubuntu touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the review on [Webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/ubuntu-phone-review-bq-aquaris-e45.html), the bq Aquaris 4.5 uses Ubuntu 14.10 (r17) (See timestamp 2:45 in the Youtube video).

Comment: Thanks for the specific timestamp in video :) Between i could see the stable channel in the name of Bq-aqua in Ubuntu installer app, installed the latest stable one. It shows the version as 14.10(r15). Its as near as you mentioned. Let me rule the world with this.